# bootstrap collapse removes all styling from link

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link that expands to show a div, using bootstrap collapse. When I click on the link, it expands the div as expected, but the styling on the link goes away. When I click on other 'ajaxy' links on the page, the style reappears

CSS:

```
a, a:hover, a:visited {
 color: red;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href='#about' aria-expanded="false" aria-controls='about'>About</a>
<div class='row'>
  <div class="collapse" id='about'>
    <div>
      About text shown here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/p11m4j3s/4/) is the jsfiddle for the repro

The link is red and without underline first. After clicking on it, the div expands. Now, the link is underlined. Move cursor away from the link and the link also becomes default (blue) color.

Comment: [Can't seem to reproduce your problem](http://www.bootply.com/1aAhW81zlS)

Comment: add same rules to a:focus too